# Recreate behavior "background-attachment: fixed" with a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I'm trying to recreate [this effect](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ScrollingLayout/) that is achieved using the CSS property `background-attachment:fixed`, but I would recreate that effect using divs, I would recreate that on a `h1` tag for example.
Is that possible? 
Thanks

Comment: can you pease show your try ?

Comment: I've know no idea from where to start, that's why I posted here. I'm looking for real example to inspect but I haven't  found anything yet :(

Answer (score 1):

you have to customised http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ScrollingLayout/js/cbpFixedScrollLayout.min.js
to achieve " I would recreate that effect using divs, I would recreate that on a h1 tag for example" instead "section" as it has below code

```
var cbpFixedScrollLayout=(function(){var a={$sections:$("#cbp-fbscroller > section")...
```

so it will always create this effect on section element.
so if you want to create it any other tag rather than section then you have yo customise above js, please try to implement it first .